# preventdefault in multiple arguments

Tags: jquery

I've made a menu which one must slide to the section and I have problem because I try to `preventDefault()` the event but I can't add this in the arguments because I passed there another argument. Thanks for help :D
...

```
$(function () {
  var home = $('.homeMenu');
  var homeSection = $('#slide-header');

  var about = $('.aboutMenu');
  var aboutSection = $('#about-us');

  var service = $('.servicesMenu');
  var serviceSection = $('#services');

  var products = $('.productMenu');
  var productSection = $('#img-boxes');

  var contact = $('.contactMenu');
  var contactSection = $('#contact');

  function slide(param2) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(param2).offset().top
    }, 1000);
  };

  home.on('click', function(){
    slide(homeSection)
  });

  about.on('click', function(){
    slide(aboutSection);
  })

  service.on('click', function(){
    slide(serviceSection);
  })

  products.on('click', function(){
    slide(productSection);
  })

  contact.on('click', function(){
    slide(contactSection);
  })
})
```

```html
<body>

    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top main-navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top " role="navigation">
   
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <a href="#navi" class="navbar-brand">Unikas</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigate">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navigate">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav items-list">
                <li><a href="#slide-header" class="homeMenu">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about-us" class="aboutMenu">O nas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services" class="servicesMenu">Usługi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#img-boxes" class="productMenu">Produkty</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="contactMenu">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
</nav>

    <header>
        <div class="header-content" id="slide-header">
            <div class="header-in text-center">
                <h1>Unikas</h1>
                <h2>najlepsze kasy fiskalne 
                w najniższych cenach</h2>
                
                <hr>
                
                <p>Od lat specjalizujemy się w kasach fiskalnych oraz usługach z nimi związanymi.<br> Najważniejsza dla nas jest jakość wykonywanych usług oraz zadowolenie klienta </p>
                
                <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Zobacz więcej</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="about-us" id="about-us">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                    <h2>Mamy to czego potrzebujesz</h2>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Setki zadowolonych klientów, najniższe ceny oraz najwyższej jakości są gwarantem naszej jakości. Wystarczy spojrzeć na nasze ceny i już wiadomo dlaczego jesteśmy numerem jeden na rynku</p>
                    <a href="services" class="btn btn-default btn-xl">Sprawdź nasze usługi</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section class="services" id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Usługi</h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-container">
                        <h2><a href="#myModal1" role="button" class="btn btn-large bt-primary" data-toggle="modal"><span class="icon-bar glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span></a></h2>
                        <h3>Fiskalizacja</h3>
<!--                        <p>Fiskalizacja kas fiskalnych</p>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-container">
                        <h2><a href="#myModal2" role="button" class="btn btn-large bt-primary" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></h2>
                        <h3>Przeglądy</h3>
<!--                        <p>Expresowo i tanio wykonywane przeglądy urządzeń</p>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-container">
                        <h2><a href="#myModal3" role="button" class="btn btn-large bt-primary" data-toggle="modal"><span class="services-icons glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></a></h2>
                        <h3>Aktualizacja oprogramowania</h3>
<!--                        <p>Aktualizujemy urządzenia natychmiast po pojawieniu się nowego oprogramowania</p>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-container">
                        <h2><a href="#myModal4" role="button" class="btn btn-large bt-primary" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></a></h2>
                        <h3>Naprawa urządzeń</h3>
<!--                        <p>Urządzenia zawsze posiadają gwarancję. Natychmiastowa naprawa</p>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section id="img-boxes" >
       <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Produkty</h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6  img-center-1 img-center">
                    
                        <img src="img/aclas_kobra_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        <div class="img-box-after">
                            <div class="img-box-after-content">
                                <div class="img-text-faded">Kasa fiskalna KOS1</div>
                                <div class="img-name">899zł</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 img-center-2 img-center">
                        <img src="img/aclas_kos_10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        <div class="img-box-after">
                            <div class="img-box-after-content">
                                <div class="img-text-faded">Kasa fiskalna KOS10</div>
                                <div class="img-name">
                                    999zł
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 img-center">
                   
                        <img src="img/aclas_kobra_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        <div class="img-box-after">
                            <div class="img-box-after-content">
                                <div class="img-text-faded">Kasa fiskalna KOS1</div>
                                <div class="img-name">
                                    899zł
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 img-center">
                    
                        <img src="img/aclas_kos_10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        <div class="img-box-after">
                            <div class="img-box-after-content">
                                <div class="img-text-faded">Kasa fiskalna KOS10</div>
                                <div class="img-name">
                                    999zł
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 img-center">
                    
                        <img src="img/aclas_kobra_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        <div class="img-box-after">
                            <div class="img-box-after-content">
                                <div class="img-text-faded">Kasa fiskalna KOS1</div>
                                <div class="img-name">
                                    899zł
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 img-center">
                  
                        <img src="img/aclas_kobra_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        <div class="img-box-after">
                            <div class="img-box-after-content">
                                <div class="img-text-faded">Kasa fiskalna KOS1</div>
                                <div class="img-name">
                                    899zł
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <aside class="background-dark-theme">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div>
                <h2>Posiadamy także wysokiej jakości kamery</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <footer id="contact">
        <div class="container footer-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" footer-text col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center ">
                    <h2 class="heading">Skontaktuj się z nami!</h2>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Strona nie obejmuje wszystkich dostępnych przez nas produktów. Realizujemy także specjalne zamówienia. Jeśli interesuje Cię konretny produkt - skontaktuj się z nami a doradzimy Ci</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                   <i class="fa fa-phone fa-3x sr-contact"></i>
                    <p>555-555-555</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                   <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-3x sr-contact"></i>
                    <p><a href="mailto:unikas@poczta.pl">unikas@poczta.pl</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center map">
                    <iframe class="map-frame" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1518.8527286598437!2d-3.708282973942787!3d40.41537539481598!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd42287ed85fe0d9%3A0xd202c4f0d67625e8!2sPlaza+Mayor%2C+Madryt%2C+Madrid%2C+Hiszpania!5e0!3m2!1spl!2spl!4v1491643777976" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    
    <div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Fiskalizacja</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Zajmujemy się stałą fiskalizacją urządzeń. Usługa odbywa się w sposób szybki i w dowolnym dla klienta terminie</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Przeglądy</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Dokonujemy starych przeglądów urządzeń fiskalnych zakupionych przez klienta</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Aktualizacja oprogramowania</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Nasze produkty zawsze posiadają najnowsze oprogramowanie.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal4" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Naprawa urządzeń</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Każda usterka urządzenia jest przez nas błyskawicznie naprawiana</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Call `preventDefault()` on the event passed to the `click` handler. You should also DRY up your code. If you can add the HTML I can give you an example fo how to do this

Comment: i'll put the html. Thanks for help